# 3 inline-block divs one higher than the other 2

Tags: html, css

I am creating a CSS style chart project and i created a container div with 3 smaller divs inside. The container has the title "___ styles" then the 3 divs have the styles ex. fonts, colors. The first container div holds 3 colored boxes of equal height and width. I coped that exact code to create boxes of fonts.

Now I have 3 font box divs with about the same amount of content. The first div is higher than the others and im not sure why.  The "Alkatra" font box is higher.

```css
h1{
  font-family:'Roboto', serif;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.color-container, .font-container{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width:100%;
  
}

h2{
  margin:5px;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", serif;
}

.color-panel{
  width:30%;
  margin:5px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px black dotted;
}

.font-panel{
  width:30%;
  margin:5px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px black dotted;
  background-color: beige;
}

.coolblue{
  background-color: #005073;
}

.pink{
  background-color: #FFC0CB;
}

.orange{
  background-color: #FFA500;
}

#roboto{
  font-family:"Roboto", serif;

}

#alkatra{
  font-family: "Alkatra", serif;

}

#opensans{
  font-family: "Open Sans", serif;

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alkatra&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My CSS style guide</h1>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="color-container">
        <h2>Color styles:</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="color-panel coolblue">
          <h2>Cool blue</h2>
          <p>Hex: #005073</p>
        </div>
        <div class="color-panel pink">
          <h2>Pink</h2>
          <p>Hex: #FFC0CB</p>
        </div>
        <div class="color-panel orange">
          <h2>Orange</h2>
          <p>Hex: #FFA500</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="font-container">
        <h2>Font styles:</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="font-panel alkatra">
          <h2 id="alkatra">Alkatra</h2>
          <p>Hex: #005073</p>
        </div>
        <div class="font-panel opensans">
          <h2 id="opensans">Open Sans</h2>
          <p>Hex: #FFC0CB</p>
        </div>
        <div class="font-panel roboto">
          <h2 id="roboto">Roboto</h2>
          <p>Hex: #FFA500</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Im new to web design and not too good at CSS. All simple CSS solutions are extremely helpful!

Comment: you want them equal in height or aligned at the top

Comment: It can be solved by adding line height. please check here https://jsfiddle.net/cjt8y5eh/

Comment: I want them to be equal in height, and also aligned at the top.

Comment: they are equal in height. check please